# What is the bash pipe identity?

Tags: bash, posix

In Posix, what is the `bash` pipe identity? That is, the program which copies `stdin` to `stdout`?

Answer (score 3):

The Posix bash pipe identity is `cat -`.

Comment: Just `cat` is sufficient.